# how can i can disable the syntax-highlighting in vsc

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Hi this highlighting in VSC kills my brain like 3 month.
please give me some idea how to disable it or turn it a little bit down :P

[image: Highliting]

Thank you :)

Comment: i disabled something now it is away xD